# >In how many ways can 5 letters be selected from the word INSTITUTE?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can $5$ letters be selected and arranged from the word INSTITUTE?

MyApproach:

I N S T U E

$2$ $1$ $1$ $3$ $1$ $1$

From these I have to select $5$.I can have following cases.

Case1:

Taking $1$ from each and taking $1$ from either I  or T .

The given combination and arrangements can be $6C5$ . $5!$

Similarly,other cases can be

Case 2: $1$,$1$,$1$,$2$ arrangements : $5!$/$2!$

Case 3: $1$,$1$,$3$   arrangements :$5!$/$3!$

Case 4: $1$,$2$,$2$   arrangements :$5!$/$2!$ . $2!$

Case 5: $2$,$3$     arrangements :$5!$/$2!$ . $3!$

I can calculate arrangements but I am unable to calculate selections for the Cases 2,3,4,5.

> Can anyone give the hint about how to selection can be made in these parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\bf{INSTITUTE}$ Contain $\bf{\left\{2I,N,S,3T,U,E\right\}}$

Now we will form Different cases

$\bullet\; $ If all letters are different, Then we will take $5$ different letters

So total no. of arrangement $\displaystyle = \underbrace{\binom{6}{5}}_{\bf{select\; 5\; diff.\; letters}}\times \underbrace{5!}_{\bf{arrange\; these\; 5\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ If $2$ letters are same and other $3$ letters are different.

So we will take a $1$ pair of letter from $2$ pair letter and other $3$ from $5$ different letters

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle =\underbrace{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{5}{3}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{5!}{2!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ Here $2$ same letters are of same kind and other $2$ are of same kind

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle \underbrace{\binom{2}{2}\times \binom{4}{1}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ Here $3$ same letter are of same kind and other $2$ letter are different

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle = \underbrace{\binom{1}{1}\times \binom{5}{2}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{5!}{3!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

$\bullet\; $ Here $3$ same letter are of same kind and other $2$ letter are of same kind

So tatal no. of ways $\displaystyle = \underbrace{\binom{1}{1}\times \binom{1}{1}}_{\bf{selection \; of \; letters}}\times \underbrace{\frac{5!}{2!\times 3!}}_{\bf{arrangement\; of\; letters}}$

So Total no. of ways $ = $ add all above cases.

Comment: In 3rd bulleted point, shouldn't it be C(4,1) ?

Comment: Why don't you use exponential generating function for simplicity?